# Can I use HTTP Requests GET and POST on Firebase Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, http-post, google-cloud-firestore, http-get

I'm new to using Firebase Close Firestore and I'm wondering if I can use HTTP GET and POST to modify the data.

If yes, where can I find the GET/POST url for Firestore? and what parameters do I have to enter?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is the Firestore Rest API. [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api#making_rest_calls) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/) will help.